# Is it possible to get values of checkboxes that are within a dynamically changed div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DmWxt/160/)

```
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' />&nbsp;Group A</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;Group B</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;Group C</p>
<div id='show'></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch(n)
    {
            case '1':
                  $('#show').html("<input id='f1input' type='checkbox'>File 1</input></br><input id='f2input' type='checkbox'>File 2</input>");
                  break;
            case '2':
                  $('#show').html("<input id='f3input' type='checkbox'>File 3</input></br><input id='f4input' type='checkbox'>File 4</input>");
                  break;
            case '3':
                  $('#show').html("<input id='f5input' type='checkbox'>File 5</input></br><input id='f6input' type='checkbox'>File 6</input>");
                  break;
        }
    });
});
```

So I've found this example on how to change the content of a div upon selection of a radio button. My problem is retrieving values within that div upon the user hitting a submit button.

I can retrieve values of the checkboxes in the div at the time the submit button is clicked, but I cannot retrieve the values of any other checkboxes. 
So for example in the js fiddle demo if I check "File 1" in Group A, and "File 5" in Group C, I can retrieve the values of "File 5" and "File 6" (or whatever checkboxes were being displayed when the submit button was hit) but have no way of knowing that "File 1" is checked. Is it at all possible to achieve this?

Comment: Add name attributes to your checkboxes, or they won't be submitted.

Comment: You'll need a lot of intercepting if you want to track values of checkboxes that are entirely removed from the document at times. I heavily suggest wrapping each set in a div or span and setting `display: none` on it, rather than completely replacing the elements.

Comment: Agree with Siguza. Basically when you call `$('#show').html(...)` you are replacing the contents of that div. So previous checkboxes (and their selection) is gone when you change radio button selection. So you can't get it on click of submit as per your current implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @James suggested you need to add a name to your checkboxes, and as @Siguza suggested it would better to have all your fields in the begging. Then all you need to do is hide/show them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").hide();
  $('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function() {
    var n = $(this).val();
    var selector = "#show-" + n; //Create a selector based on the id
    $(".show").hide(); //Hide all the checkbox containers
    $(selector).show(); //Show only the related container
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' />&nbsp;Group A</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;Group B</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;Group C</p>
<div id='show-1' class="show">
  <input type='checkbox' name='file1'>File 1 <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='file2'>File 2 <br>
</div>
<div id='show-2' class="show">
  <input type='checkbox' name='file3'>File 3 <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='file4'>File 4 <br>
</div>
<div id='show-3' class="show">
  <input type='checkbox' name='file5'>File 5 <br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='file6'>File 6 <br>
</div>
```

If you are in the neccesity of recreating everything every time you change your radio, you could try the following code, it uses an object to store your data:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Use an object to store your data
  function MyData() {
    var self = this;
    self.file1 = false;
    self.file2 = false;
    self.file3 = false;
    self.file4 = false;
    self.file5 = false;
    return self;
  }

  var data = new MyData(); //create a new instance of your object

  //On change save your value
  $('#show').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    data[self.prop('name')] = self.is(":checked");
    console.log(data);
  });

  //Set the values once again
  function setValue(value, inputName) {
    var input = $(inputName);
    value ? input.attr('checked', 'checked') : input.removeAttr('checked');
  }


  $('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function() {
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch (n) {
      case '1':
        $('#show').html(
          "<input  type='checkbox' name='file1'>File 1</br>" +
          "<input type='checkbox' name='file2'>File 2"
        );
        setValue(data.file1, "input[name=file1]"); //Set the values when created
        setValue(data.file2, "input[name=file2]");
        break;
      case '2':
        $('#show').html(
          "<input  type='checkbox' name='file3'>File 3</br>" +
          "<input  type='checkbox' name='file4'>File 4"
        );
        setValue(data.file3, "input[name=file3]");
        setValue(data.file4, "input[name=file4]");
        break;
      case '3':
        $('#show').html(
          "<input  type='checkbox' name='file5'>File 5</br>" +
          "<input  type='checkbox' name='file6'>File 6</input>"
        );
        setValue(data.file5, "input[name=file5]");
        setValue(data.file6, "input[name=file6]");
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' />&nbsp;Group A</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;Group B</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;Group C</p>
<div id='show'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that the jQuery you've got is actually destroying the checkboxes each time it switches between groups.

The `.html()` method you are calling is replacing the inside of `<div id="show">` with whatever you are passing into it (in this case the groups of checkboxes). The old checkboxes are just annihilated in the process, which means you can't know what the value was.

There are a few ways to fix this that come to mind:

1. Store or remove each value in an object as a person clicks on it, then use that object when you hit submit.
2. Wrap the checkbox groups in divs that all live in `<div id="show">`, and hide/show them as the radio buttons are clicked.

I think the first solution is a better way to handle it from a programming perspective, but the second solution can be easier to understand if you are new to programming or just starting out with jQuery. Here's a demo of the second solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // Actual solution, showing and hiding the different divs on each click.
  $('input[name=content_type]').on('change', function(){
    var n = '#files-group-' + $(this).val();

    // Here we are adding and removing a class name so that our CSS can handle the presentation of what is visible and what isn't.
    $('.active-files-group').removeClass('active-files-group');
    $(n).addClass('active-files-group');
  });
  
  

  // This is just to show the changing values in the JFiddle and has no real bearing on your question.
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {

    var listOfCheckboxStates = $('#show input[type="checkbox"]').map(function () {
     return $(this).prop('value') + ': ' + $(this).prop('checked'); 
    });

    var showValuesData = '';

    [].forEach.call(listOfCheckboxStates, function (item) {
      showValuesData += item + '<br />';
    });

    $('#show-values').html('').html('<p>' + showValuesData + '</p>');
  });
});
```

```css
.files-group { display: none; }
.active-files-group { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='1' />&nbsp;Group A</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='2' />&nbsp;Group B</p>
<p><input type='radio' name='content_type' value='3' />&nbsp;Group C</p>
<div id='show'>
  <div id="files-group-1" class="files-group">
    <input value="File 1" id='f1input' name="f1input" type='checkbox'>File 1</input>
    </br>
    <input value="File 2" id='f2input' name="f2input" type='checkbox'>File 2</input>
  </div>
  <div id="files-group-2" class="files-group">
    <input value="File 3"t id='f3input' name="f3input" type='checkbox'>File 3</input>
    </br>
    <input value="File 4" id='f4input' name="f4input" type='checkbox'>File 4</input>
  </div>
  <div id="files-group-3" class="files-group">
    <input value="File 5" id='f5input' name="f5input" type='checkbox'>File 5</input>
    </br>
    <input value="File 6" id='f6input' name="f6input" type='checkbox'>File 6</input>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Values</h3>
<div id="show-values">

</div>
```